# Angular UI Typeahead custom directive - model not updated on select

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I made custom directive that use Angular UI typeahead directive inside, but not working as expected. In my directive model is not updating on select. Anybody helps with that ? For testing i used static array instead of http service. Plunker [HERE](https://plnkr.co/edit/WY2ITd3vgYMsia7pMeqk).

```
.directive('httpDictionary', ['$compile', function($compile){
    return {
        scope: {
        },
        restrict: 'A',
        controllerAs: "dm",
        controller: ['$scope', '$http', 'ARRAY', function($scope, $http, ARRAY){
           var dm = this;
           dm.dict = function(val){
            return ARRAY; // for testing only
            // return $http.get($scope.dictionaryUrl, { ...
           } 
        }],
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
            scope.dictionaryUrl = attributes.httpDictionary;
            element.removeAttr('http-dictionary'); // avoid loop
            element.attr('uib-typeahead', 'd for d in dm.dict($viewValue)');
            $compile(element)(scope);
        }
    };    
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

To help with binding to a model, I usually use `uib-typeahead` setting `typeahead-on-select`. That way, you can check against or execute some additional code when the new model is set.

I made a plunker off your code found [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/R0WWvjcGSNWgyUOxQlbT?p=preview) but made some small tweaks:

- I isolated the input text field into its own view so as to separate the functionality from the parent view.
- I passed the `test` model to the directive's scope attribute and then bound it to the directives controller (using `bindToController` attribute) so if you ever needed the `test` model to communicate with the parent controller in the future, you could do so.

Hopes this helps.

Comment: Your code works ok, but directive in that form (`restrict:'E'`) is not usable with other directives. I need that works as attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I made this works like below. Plunker code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/STpznIcTpn3Swuz3TWPz). I've bind ngModel in directive scope and used `typeahead-on-select` callback function. I don't think so this is elegant, but works. I've been thinking about using `$watch`, but without success. If You have a better soultion, i'll be glad.

```
.directive('httpDictionary', ['$compile', function($compile){
    return {
        scope: {
          ngModel: '='
        },
        restrict: 'A',
        controllerAs: "dm",
        controller: ['$scope', '$http', 'ARRAY', function($scope, $http, ARRAY){
           var dm = this;
           dm.dict = function(val){
            return ARRAY; // for testing only
            // return $http.get($scope.dictionaryUrl, { ...
           } 
           dm.select = function($model) {
              $scope.ngModel = $model;
           }           
        }],
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
            scope.dictionaryUrl = attributes.httpDictionary;
            element.removeAttr('http-dictionary'); // avoid loop
            element.attr('uib-typeahead', 'd for d in dm.dict($viewValue)');
            element.attr('typeahead-on-select','dm.select($model)');
            element = $compile(element)(scope);
        }
    };    
}])
```